# How do I set up SharePoint Server with an Azure SQL Database Server?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sql-server, azure, windows-server

I am trying to create a SharePoint Server environment. I have an Azure subscription, so I created a Windows Server 2019 virtual machine and set up Active Directory. I also created an Azure SQL Database server (mysql.database.windows.net). I downloaded SharePoint Server on to the Windows virtual machine, and I tried to connect it to the Azure SQL Database, but it said Windows Authentication was not supported.

Is it possible to use an Azure SQL Database Server for SharePoint Server?

Answer (score 2):

Did you follow these instructions:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/deploy-azure-sql-managed-instance-with-sharepoint-servers-2016-2019

Answer (score 2):

According to the official [document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/deploy-azure-sql-managed-instance-with-sharepoint-servers-2016-2019#environment), you need to host the databases on Azure SQL Managed Instance with **SQL authentication**.

One more reference for you: [Hosting SharePoint Content Databases in SQL Azure.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sambetts/hosting-sharepoint-content-databases-in-sql-azure)

Comment: How do I connect with SQL authentication? In the product configuration wizard, there is no option to change the authentication type, and in PowerShell, it will only accept a PSCredential.

Comment: @RalphGreene According to the document (first link), the databases on SQL MI should be hosted with SQL authentication, but you will need SharePoint farm service account credential in PowerShell/SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard, and Azure SQL Managed Instance database login credential in the section “DatabaseCredentials”.